# Prevent http page from redirecting to https page

Tags: apache, ssl, browser, https, hsts

I have a website (userbob.com) that normally serves all pages as https.   However, I am trying to have one subdirectory (userbob.com/tools/) always serve content as http.   Currently, it seems like Chrome's HSTS feature (which I don't understand how it works) is forcing my site's pages to load over https.   I can go to chrome://net-internals/#hsts and delete my domain from Chrome's HSTS set, and the next query will work as I want without redirecting to an https version.   However, if I try to load the page a second time, it ends up redirecting again.   The only way I can get it to work is if I go to chrome://net-internals/#hsts and delete my domain from Chrome's HSTS set after each request.   How do I let browsers know that I want all my pages from userbob.com/tools/ to load as http?  My site uses an apache/tomcat web server.

(Just FYI, the reason I want the pages in the tools directory to serve pages over http instead of https is because some of them are meant to iframe http pages.   If I try to iframe an http page from an https page I end up getting mixed-content errors.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTTP Strict Transport Security (or HSTS) is a setting your site can send to browsers which says "I only want to use HTTPS on my site - if someone tries to go to a HTTP link, automatically upgrade them to HTTPS before you send the request". It basically won't allow you to send any HTTP traffic, either accidentally or intentionally.

This is a security feature. HTTP traffic can be intercepted, read, altered and redirected to other domains. HTTPS-only websites should redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS, but there are various security issues/attacks if any requests are still initially sent over HTTP so HSTS prevents this.

The way HSTS works is that your website sends a HTTP Header `Strict-Transport-Security` with a value of, for example, `max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains` on your HTTPS requests. The browser caches this and activates HSTS for 31536000 seconds (1 year), in this example. You can see this HTTP Header in your browsers web developer tools or by using a site like https://securityheaders.io . By using the `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` site you are able to clear that cache and allow HTTP traffic again. However as soon as you visit the site over HTTPS it will send the Header again and the browser will revert back to HTTPS-only.

So to permanently remove this setting you need to stop sending that `Strict-Transport-Security` Header. Find this in your Apache/Tomcat server and turn it off. Or better yet change it to `max-age=0; includeSubDomains` for a while first (which tells the browser to clear the cache after 0 seconds and so turns it off without having to visit `chrome://net-internals/#hsts`, as long as you visit the site over HTTPS to pick up this Header, and then remove the Header completely later.

Once you turn off HSTS you can revert back to having some pages on HTTPS and some on HTTP with standard redirects.

However it would be remiss of me to not warn you against going back to HTTP. HTTPS is the new standard and there is a general push to encourage all sites to move to HTTPS and penalise those that do not. Read his post for more information:

https://www.troyhunt.com/life-is-about-to-get-harder-for-websites-without-https/

While you are correct that you cannot frame HTTP content on a HTTPS page, you should consider if there is another way to address this problem. A single HTTP page on your site can cause security problems like leaking cookies (if they are not set up correctly). Plus frames are horrible and shouldn't be used anymore :-)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer.   I ended up modifying my tools to only support iframing https pages.

Comment: How to remove Strict-Transport-Security would have been useful in the answer

Comment: That depends entirely on how it’s added. Could be in Apache config. Could be from a back end system. Could be preloaded. So there is not enough information in the question to be able to answer that. Additionally because of the number of ways to have this I don’t think that would be that useful an addition to the answer For others either.

Answer (score 1):

You can use rewrite rules to redirect https requests to http inside of subdirectory. Create an `.htaccess` file inside `tools` directory and add the following content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Make sure that apache `mod_rewrite` is enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.   However if I do that Chrome ends up displaying a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error.   It seems as if my server tries to force http in this way, Chrome insists that the page should be loaded as https and the server responds with a 301 redirect to the http page then Chrome requests the https page and this cycle repeats until Chrome gives up.

Answer (score 1):

Basically **any** HTTP 301 response from an HTTPS request indicating a target redirect to HTTP should never be honored at all by any browser, those servers doing that are clearly violating basic security, or are severaly compromized.
However a 301 reply to an HTTPS request can still redirect to another HTTPS target (including on another domain, provided that other CORS requirements are met).

If you navigate an HTTPS link (or a javascript event handler) and the browser starts loading that HTTPS target which replies with 301 redirect to HTTP, the behavior of the browser should be like if it was a 500 server error, or a connection failure (DNS name not resolved, server not responding timeout).

Such server-side redirect are clearly invalid. And website admins should never do that ! If they want to close a service and inform HTTPS users that the service is hosted elsewhere and no longer secure, they MUST return a valid HTTPS response page with NO redirect at all, and this should really be a 4xx error page (most probably 404 PAGE NOT FOUND) and they should not redirect to another HTTPS service (e.g. a third-party hosted search engine or parking page) which does not respect CORS requirements, or sends false media-types (it is acceptable to not honor the requested language and display that page in another language).

Browsers that implement HSTS are perfectly correct and going to the right direction. But I really think that CORS specifications are a mess, just tweaked to still allow advertizing network to host and control themselves the ads they broadcast to other websites.

I strongly think that serious websites that still want to display ads (or any tracker for audience measurement) for valid reasons can host these ads/trackers themselves, on their own domain and in the same protocol: servers can still get themselves the ads content they want to broadcast by downloading/refreshing these ads themselves and maintaining their own local cache. They can track their audience themselves by collecting the data they need and want and filtering it on their own server if they want this data to be analysed by a third party: websites will have to seriously implement thelselves the privacy requirements.

I hate now those too many websites that, when visited, are being tracked by dozens of third parties, including very intrusive ones like Facebook and most advertizing networks, plus many very weak third party services that have very poor quality/security and send very bad content they never control (including fake ads, fake news, promoting illegal activities, illegal businesses, invalid age rating...).

Let's return to the origin of the web: one site, one domain, one third party. This does not mean that they cannot link to other third party sites, but these must done only with an explicit user action (tapping or clicking), and visitors MUST be able to kn ow wherre this will go to, or which content will be displayed.

This is even possible for inserting videos (e.g. Youtube) in news articles: the news website can host themselves a cache of static images for the frame and icons for the "play" button: when users click that icon, it will start activating the third party video, and in that case the thirf party will interact directly with that user and can collect other data. But the unactivated contents will be tracked only by the origin website, under their own published policy.

Answer (score 0):

In my local development environment I use apache server. What worked for me was :
Open you config file in `sites-availabe/yoursite.conf`. then add the following line inside your virtualhost:
`Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=0"`. Restart your server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Node server then, change in app.tsx
Follow: [HelmetJS](https://helmetjs.github.io/)

Remove-

```
app.use(helmet())
```

Use-

```
app.use(
        helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
            directives: {
                defaultSrc: ["'self' *"],
                upgradeInsecureRequests: null,
            },
        }),
    )
```

Or Use-

```
app.use(
        helmet.hsts({
            maxAge: 0,
        }),
    )
```